# how to embed styled google map in your site

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I had used used google map editing service from here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

now this link provided me two things :
1. a json code
2. the google api link

but i dont know how to use json in my html, earlier i had embed simple google map in my site from javascript [something like var google new map]. plz help me in adding this json code to my javascript or html.

here is the JSON code

```
[
{
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#242f3e"
  }
]
},
{
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#746855"
  }
]
},
{
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#242f3e"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "administrative.country",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#af01ab"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "administrative.locality",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#fe70fb"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "administrative.locality",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#d59563"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "administrative.province",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#fe01f8"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "poi",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#d59563"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "poi.park",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#169c03"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "poi.park",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#6b9a76"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "road",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#38414e"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "road",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#212a37"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "road",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#9ca5b3"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.arterial",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#7274d3"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#4d4ddb"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#1f2835"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#f3d19c"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.local",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#9898b8"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "transit",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#2f3948"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "transit.line",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#fafe52"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "transit.station",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#d59563"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "transit.station.rail",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#fafe52"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "water",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#169ba3"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "water",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#515c6d"
  }
]
},
{
"featureType": "water",
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#17263c"
  }
]
}
]
```

and this is [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=YOUR_API_KEY&center=29.921068146058925,433.86609008312223&zoom=17&format=png&maptype=roadmap&style=element:geometry%7Ccolor:0x242f3e&style=element:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x746855&style=element:labels.text.stroke%7Ccolor:0x242f3e&style=feature:administrative.country%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xaf01ab&style=feature:administrative.locality%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfe70fb&style=feature:administrative.locality%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xd59563&style=feature:administrative.province%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfe01f8&style=feature:poi%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xd59563&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x169c03&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x6b9a76&style=feature:road%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x38414e&style=feature:road%7Celement:geometry.stroke%7Ccolor:0x212a37&style=feature:road%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x9ca5b3&style=feature:road.arterial%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x7274d3&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x4d4ddb&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:geometry.stroke%7Ccolor:0x1f2835&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xf3d19c&style=feature:road.local%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x9898b8&style=feature:transit%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x2f3948&style=feature:transit.line%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfafe52&style=feature:transit.station%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xd59563&style=feature:transit.station.rail%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfafe52&style=feature:water%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x169ba3&style=feature:water%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x515c6d&style=feature:water%7Celement:labels.text.stroke%7Ccolor:0x17263c&size=480x360)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=YOUR_API_KEY&center=29.921068146058925,433.86609008312223&zoom=17&format=png&maptype=roadmap&style=element:geometry%7Ccolor:0x242f3e&style=element:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x746855&style=element:labels.text.stroke%7Ccolor:0x242f3e&style=feature:administrative.country%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xaf01ab&style=feature:administrative.locality%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfe70fb&style=feature:administrative.locality%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xd59563&style=feature:administrative.province%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfe01f8&style=feature:poi%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xd59563&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x169c03&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x6b9a76&style=feature:road%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x38414e&style=feature:road%7Celement:geometry.stroke%7Ccolor:0x212a37&style=feature:road%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x9ca5b3&style=feature:road.arterial%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x7274d3&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x4d4ddb&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:geometry.stroke%7Ccolor:0x1f2835&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xf3d19c&style=feature:road.local%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x9898b8&style=feature:transit%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x2f3948&style=feature:transit.line%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfafe52&style=feature:transit.station%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xd59563&style=feature:transit.station.rail%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfafe52&style=feature:water%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x169ba3&style=feature:water%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x515c6d&style=feature:water%7Celement:labels.text.stroke%7Ccolor:0x17263c&size=480x360
```

Comment: you need google map APi key for this

Comment: @IsmailFarooq i have my api key but how to add json

Comment: the url you provided has missing the API KEY "YOUR_API_KEY" see example https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: i know i think it is not allowed to share on stack overlow. because everytime when i share my api key someone edit my post and remove api key. so this time i didnt add one @IsmailFarooq

Comment: Thanks for your help it works for me.Please avoid discussion. And, please up vote this Question. It is already graving my reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following step to show the map

1. Get Google Map [Api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)
2. Enable Google Static Maps API https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend/overview?PROJECTNAME
3. Treat Google Static code like an image you can use HTML or CSS to display it.

**Example**

```
<img width="600" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=YOUR_API_KEY&center=29.921068146058925,433.86609008312223&zoom=17&format=png&maptype=roadmap&style=element:geometry%7Ccolor:0x242f3e&style=element:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x746855&style=element:labels.text.stroke%7Ccolor:0x242f3e&style=feature:administrative.country%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xaf01ab&style=feature:administrative.locality%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfe70fb&style=feature:administrative.locality%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xd59563&style=feature:administrative.province%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfe01f8&style=feature:poi%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xd59563&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x169c03&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x6b9a76&style=feature:road%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x38414e&style=feature:road%7Celement:geometry.stroke%7Ccolor:0x212a37&style=feature:road%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x9ca5b3&style=feature:road.arterial%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x7274d3&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x4d4ddb&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:geometry.stroke%7Ccolor:0x1f2835&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xf3d19c&style=feature:road.local%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x9898b8&style=feature:transit%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x2f3948&style=feature:transit.line%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfafe52&style=feature:transit.station%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xd59563&style=feature:transit.station.rail%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xfafe52&style=feature:water%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x169ba3&style=feature:water%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x515c6d&style=feature:water%7Celement:labels.text.stroke%7Ccolor:0x17263c&size=480x360" alt="Google Map of Albany, NY">
```

See [here](http://staticmapmaker.com/google/) for more

If you want to do it via JSON you need to see google [official example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)